# How do I get all files for my django app into one folder?

Tags: python, django

I currently have a Django app named reserve.  In the folder named "reserve" I have most of the content of my app (views.py, urls.py, models.py, templates folder).  However, I have a folder outside of "reserve" named "booking" that has only my settings.py.  I tried consolidating by putting the settings.py in "booking" into "reserve" but I seem to be getting an error.  Any advice on how to have only one folder with all contents?

The error I get is: ImportError: Could not import settings 'booking.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named booking.settings

```
overall project folder
    booking folder
        settings.py
        init.py


    reserve folder (the app)
        views.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what version of django are you using? what command are you running ? assuming that you are just trying to run a command using `manage.py`  you could just chnage manage.py to reflect this if you are going to permanently keep this project structure

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

you should change `os.environ.setdefault` to the correct directory for your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have manage.py at the overal project directory?  I'm also assuming you want to just `runserver`.

It seems you moved the `settings.py` file outside the overal project directory.  If you do this, you'll have to specify the settings file path when you do runserver, or you can also export the django settings module to point to your new settings path (using dot notation).   In this case, I think it would be (in the command line):

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<overal-project-folder-name>.booking.settings
python manage.py runserver
```